# Why can't I restore a SQL Backup on a newer Version? Error 3169

Tags: backup, sql-server-2019, azure-sql-managed-instance

I am trying to restore a backup from an Azure Managed Instance to an SQL Server running on an Azure VM.
When running the Backup Script, I get this error Message:

```
Meldung 3169, Ebene 16, Status 1, Zeile 2
The database was backed up on a server running version 15.00.2000. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 15.00.4073. 
Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server.
```

Firstly, when running the Script

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

the managed instance seems to run on version 12.0.2000.8 and
secondly, the new SQL Server is running a newer version than the source DB from the error print, which means it shouldn't be a problem, right?

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Justus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from @@VERSION from the Managed Instance is misleading.

Because a Managed Instance is an evergreen deployment (it is ALWAYS the latest version) this means that it is always a newer version than any version of SQL Server you will get on a VM.

You will need to consider other methods such as BACPACs or replication to get your DB copy on the VM

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Martin. The versioning of Azure SQL DB and Azure SQL MI are known as V12 as compared to on-prem versions. You can backup DB from SQL Server -> Azure SQL MI but it is not backward compatible.

You will need to BACPAC or replication as an option.

On the positive note, there is a lot of request for backward compatibility and I am hearing that it might be coming in preview later this year but not 100% sure.